# Resample the time-series data to selected time interval(10 days)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a time-series data in CSV, I want to resample the time series data to 10 days interval. Using the Pandas resamples function, I can do it weekly, monthly, and yearly. But I want as selected timeframe e.g. 10 days. Below are my data and code,

```
Date
2010-01-01    26
2010-02-01    26
2010-03-01    26
2010-04-01    28
2010-05-01    26
              ..
2019-12-23    23
2019-12-24    24
2019-12-25    24
2019-12-26    24
2019-12-27    26 

import pandas as pd
Data = pd.read_csv('Weather.csv', parse_dates =["Date"], index_col ="Date")
#i want to put here selected timeframe e.g 10 days instead of weekly or monthly
weekly_resampled_data = Data.Temp_Max.resample('W').mean()
weekly_resampled_data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resample using `10D`

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,61),
                  index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-03-01', freq='D'))

df.resample('10D').mean()

              0
2020-01-01  4.8
2020-01-11  4.9
2020-01-21  5.8
2020-01-31  5.2
2020-02-10  4.9
2020-02-20  5.5
2020-03-01  8.0
```